# how to make a photo autoresize in a premade gallery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to use this premade slideshow photo gallery http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/ , but i want to change the gallery dimension to height 450px, and width:700px.... the problem is i did not know how, then i saw it depends on the height of the largest photo. But when i, firstly, saw the gallery i thought that the gallery has fixed dimension and the images are auto resized , depending on their height or width when they are shown. So how can i make this thing what i thought, to resize the image instead of resizing the entire gallery ? i mean, i will use photos bigger than 1024x768 or 768x1024, and i want my gallery to be 700x500.....for the icons of the photos i thought to crop the photo to 50x50px, how can i do also this ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work becuase I do not know the pluggin however you can try by forcing all the images a certain size with CSS. Add this to your CSS file.

```
img{
   max-width:500px;
   max-height:700px;
}
```

This will force all images to that size.

Alternatively if you want to use more images in your page then I recommend making a class for the images in the gallery to force their size.

```
.img_size{
   max-width:500px;
   max-height:700px;
}
```

Then in your image tags of the pluggin add

```
class="img_size"
```

Or you could add the *max-width* and *max-height* tags into the gallery Div and then set the *max-width* + *max-height* tags in image to *inherit*